# Setting Window.location.replace header type as GET

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Peace be upon you.

Say I'm at link `http://stackoverflow.com` then I have a `<div onclick="window.location.replace('/New/Link.html');"></div>` which As you might know that on click it goes to `/New/Link.html`, But Then due to `window.location.repace` Uses Post Method I can't back up to `http://stackoverflow.com`.

**Question:**
 can I Set the method type of `window.location.replace` as GET?

Comment: Have you tried using window.location.href='/New/Link.html'?

Comment: @PatrickHund Okay I had tried it as window.location.href('/New/Link.html'); which was wrong, yep that worked, thx

Comment: Cool, glad to help